# Zf2 Routing Issue

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new in **Zend Framework‎ 2** . i have downloaded **zend-skeleton** application its working fine.but when i created new module of album & calling album route page not found **error(404)** occurs .

I have tried to apply many types of **zf2** routes but same error message.

This is the error page which is being displayed again & again when i access album route :

[image]

*I don't know why this error is being occurred? Kindly suggest me any solution?*

Comment: show me your `module.config.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your Module.php it should look something like this

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

especially check namespace in all module files
your module.config.php should look like this

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'index' => 'Album\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),


        ),
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: And of course you need to add your new module to config\application.config.php

Comment: return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',